# MySQL as a service not running

Tags: mysql, database, service, windows-installer, failed-installation

This is my error log file

```
Beginning configuration step: Stopping Server [if necessary]
Ended configuration step: Stopping Server [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating firewall
Adding firewall rule for MYSQL56 on port 3306.
Successfully added firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating firewall

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service [if necessary]
Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Starting Server
Starting MySQL as a service
Cannot start service MYSQL56 on computer '.'.
Ended configuration step: Starting Server
```

Please advice as how and why I should fix this. I used all default options to install MySQL. I installed it using the GUI msi installer.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be a problem with the Windows User Account, which you specify during the installation configuration dialogs.

Not in your case, but FYI: Another thing that can break installation is if you change the Windows Service Name to contain blanks. It becomes a service startup command-line parameter *without* double-quotes. Foo.